# Comparing strings as dates using EF core 3

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm migrating some code from asp.net to asp.net core, and I can't find a way to compare dates in string format "yyyyMMdd", *ie Datediff(day, column, "value") == x*, the database is SQLServer and changing the column type is not an option.

I'm using reflexion which complicates things.

the code in asp.net is

```
    public static Expression ExpressionsDiffDate(Expression cte, Expression property)
    {
        MethodInfo DateDiff = typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethod("DateDiff", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(string), typeof(string) });

        if (property.Type == typeof(DateTime) || property.Type == typeof(DateTime?))
        {
            DateDiff = typeof(SqlFunctions).GetMethod("DateDiff", new Type[] { typeof(string), typeof(DateTime), typeof(DateTime) });
            property = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(DateTime?));
            cte = ConvertExpressionToDate(cte);
        }

        return Expression.Call(
                    DateDiff,
                    Expression.Constant("day"),
                    cte,
                    property
            );
    }
```

In this example I use the method datediff in the class sqlfunctions, that has plenty of overloads, depending on the column type I either use the one that takes datetime as parameters or the one that takes strings.

I managed to this for columns of type DateTime in .net core

```
    public static Expression ExpressionsDiffDate(Expression cte, Expression property)
    {
        ParameterExpression exFun = Expression.Parameter(typeof(DbFunctions));
        MethodInfo DateDiff = typeof(SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions).GetMethod("DateDiffDay", new Type[] { typeof(DbFunctions), typeof(DateTime), typeof(DateTime) });

        return Expression.Call(
                    DateDiff,
                    exFun,
                    cte,
                    property
            );
    }
```

**But I can't figure out how to do so for columns with the type string, since it does not have any overloads that take strings.**

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following "double cast" technique

```
(DateTime)(object)stringExpr
```

or

```
(DateTime?)(object)stringExpr
```

can be used to trick C# compiler to treat `string` type expression as `DateTime`, thus allows you to call `DateTime` or `DateTime?` overloads of `DateDiff` methods (or use `DateTime` operators).

EF Core query translator for SqlServer will generate `CAST` to `datetime` or `datetime2` type, which should try default SqlServer conversion from string.

e.g. something like this

```
if (property.Type == typeof(string))
    property = Expression.Convert(Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object)), typeof(DateTime));
```

Comment: Thank you very much